# Mui Grid with different size items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

Is it possible to have a grid from Material ui that could have something like:

1st item: 6 columns and 2 rows ( so it stretches on both rows if you have 8 items )
all the other items: 3columns

So basically it will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: in MUI, grid and datagrid both are different. Question title says Data Grid but body says grid. could you please clarify which one you are expecting. https://mui.com/components/grid/

Comment: Sorry, I modified the title, is the Grid, not data grid